# How to get billing information programmatically from Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I want write utility which fetches billing information for my project dynamically but I am not able to find any specific API from GCP to do the same.
I tried a couple of APIs like getBillingInfo but these APIs just give information about billing account, not the pricing.
They have the mechanism to export billing data to file but I want to do it programmatically. Is there any API to do the same?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to get the billing data from Google Cloud Platform:

- Export Billing Data to BigQuery
- Export Billing Data to a File

**For BigQuery:**

1. Enable billing export to BigQuery
2. Create a BigQuery Client
3. Run a query to get the billing data

Query to get daily cost:

```
"SELECT SUM(cost) AS cost FROM `"+ PROJECT_ID + "." + DATA_SET + "." + TABLE_NAME + "`" + "WHERE CAST(DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) AS DATE) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)"
```

**For File:**

1. Enable billing export to a file
2. Write a code to download an object from a bucket
3. Iterate through a downloaded file and perform the summation of "cost" property

Hope this helps :).